# gVim 8.2, display problem

Tags: font, color

I have a weird problem with VIM, both at work and at home (2 different computers):
When I open a text in VIM, sometimes it is displaying it correctly, sometime not (I'd say 1 every 3 it works fine, others not, it's random)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does `:set ft?` say `filetype=julia` in both cases? Does `:version` confirm it's the same version of the editor? How about `:syntax`, does it list a bunch of `julia*` syntax groups? See if setting filetype manually again fixes it, with `:set ft=julia`.

Comment: looks like syntax sync issue. Can you press `Ctrl-L` once it happens next time? Then scroll screen down and press again? Also what syntax do you use? I couldn't find julia in bundled files.

Comment: `:syntax sync fromstart` is usually a good fix

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies. 
Ctrl-L at the top of the file (not at the bottom) worked.